# The system notification sound for a trigged service in Android Kotlin Flamingo

Tags: android, kotlin, audio, service, notifications

All the following is run in Android Studio Emulator Pixel 6 pro API33.
I used a button click to start a service. When the service is started, a notification sound is played by Emulator. I did not set this sound. But after I upgraded the Android Studio Electric Eel to Android Studio Flamingo. That notification sound doesn't occur anymore.

I tried setting the sound in Emulator Pixel 6 pro setting 'Default notification sound'. But there is still no any sound when the service is started. I still want to set some sound for the triggered service.
Can anyone help? Thank you very much.